# How to update an observable collection in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working with xamarin forms. I have an observable collection and in my listview I have a number picker. How do I update my observable collection on the number picker changed event?

Comment: You should post your code to get help on that!

Comment: i just need to know  to update the observable collection and which part of my code you want to see  @mak

Comment: What is it you want to Update in your observable collection? Add and Item? Delete and Item? Change the property of an Item at the index shown on your picker? Need a bit more information if you want anything useful.

Comment: Otherwise all I can answer is update it in SelectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a csharp question, it does not depend from Xamarin.

This can help you

[Add object to ObservableCollection List object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267585/add-object-to-observablecollection-list-object)

You have Add method

Comment: yes it is xamarin i need to update the selected value only @Alessandro Caliaro

Comment: @shamnad to update a value you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the object . I suggest you to try Fody.PropertyChanged

Comment: i think INotifyPropertyChanged is used to notify the view to update the view but i need to update inside the collection too which the selected item only

Comment: I think you know the index of the selected item... You can do something like collection[index] = newvalue. Or you can try with binding

Comment: i'm not clicking on the list view i'm clicking on a button inside the list view so how can i find the position of the list view ?if the question is silly i'm sorry about that

Comment: Are you in Xamarin forms?

Comment: yes i'm in xanarin forms. Now i can update but not the selected value 
  App.Instance.ViewModel.TempList[1].cnt = Convert.ToInt32(btn_NumBtn.Text);
iam doing like this but i need the selected index instead of TempList[1]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91732/discussion-between-shamnad-and-alessandro-caliaro).

Comment: thanks @ Alessandro Caliaro it works nicely 
((our class)this.BindingContext).value= int.Parse(this.button.Text);

Comment: @shamnad sign as answered so we close the question